# Where is the .well-known folder on Heroku going to be, for a Rails 6 website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've created a website using Rails 6 on Heroku. I need to drop a file into /.well-known/ but I've no idea where that might be.

I created a folder with that name in the root of the project and checked it in to git, but it doesn't show up there.

It seems that I should use a route to do this, but I don't have a handle on the syntax to use. I basically need to expose a /.well-known/longhashedstring.txt to a 3rd party service for about a minute.

Comment: If it's same as previous versions of Rails then `.well-known` will go in `public` folder

Comment: Thanks Sharj, it apparently has not changed - created a /public/.well-known/foo.txt and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

See above answer from Sharj. Put your .well-known folder in /public for Rails 6 and all is good.